What is the word that describes a viewpoint from above and 'panning down' like in a film?
I'm trying to remember a word from when I studied for my degree in English Lit and Lang. It describes a viewpoint as if looking down from above and moving in and down, like when watching a film and the camera pans in from above and down, describing what you see.
I think it's maybe like transcendental but that feels incorrect; any ideas?

The camera would be zooming, not panning.

@TinfoilHat Moving towards or away from the subject is zooming. Moving up/down or left/right is panning.

You could try asking in [movies.se]. They're more likely to know film industry terminology.

Are you looking for crane shot?

"from above and down". Are you referring to the long zoom shot that homes in on the subject while weaving around obstacles?

@Barmar — Yes, OP said “moving in.” That’s zooming — not panning.

They said "in and down". That's zooming and panning.

@Barmar — No, down from above is zooming.

Can you provide an example of the shot, because people don't know what you're talking about? Also, do you want a technical filmmaking term or not?

In a different context the view from above is called a plan view.

Like the opening of The Simpsons?

Left-to-right motion  is panning, but technically motion up and down is tilting. (The 'pan' comes from 'panorama'.) Cinematographers don't say 'pan up'


Pedestal
Also known as a Boom up/down, our final shot is the pedestal. This involves moving the camera up or down relative to a subject. […] A pedestal shot can be used to frame a tall or high subject (such as a building) while keeping the framing at eye level.

SOURCE: Seenit 7 Basic Camera Movements (And Why They Matter!)

No, pedestal is not from above. In any case, I think OP is looking for a literary description of that effect, not a technical camera one.

@TinfoilHat  Is your suggestion "zooming" literary? That's also a typical feature on cameras. What does "…the camera pans in from above and down describing what you see." mean then? It must be a visual effect, I don't think it exists as a literary device, does it?  The same can be said for panning Is it because the OP's description is missing the "either... or"? The OP also says the word they are looking for sounds like  "transcedental" [sic]. ‍♀️

No zooming is not literary, not was it an answer; I was just correcting OP’s panning term.

Panning isn't wrong…if a camera moves up and down, from side to side that is panning, "moving in and down” is ambiguous, does it mean to get nearer its subject  and lower at the same time, or was it a typo: "in and out" vs "up and down", don't think we'll ever know.

In literature, this sounds like an omniscient point of view (sees all/“zoomed out”), shifting to a regular third person point of view (“zoomed in”):

Third-person limited There’s a clue in the name of this point of view: limited. In third-person limited, you stick to one
character’s perspective and are “zoomed in” on
them. . . .
Third-person omniscient In third-person omniscient, we still use third person (he did this, she did that, they did this). However,
omniscient is “zoomed out”. The narrative doesn’t come from the point
of view of any one character. It comes from the point of view of an
external, godlike narrator, who knows everything about the story and
its characters.
Source: Point of view: What’s the difference between
third-person limited and
omniscient?

